# bash: for file in if exists?

Tags: bash, file, loops, wildcard

So,

```
for f in *.c; do echo "That $f is the best C code I have ever seen"; done
```

if there are no c files, will gladly print

```
That *.c is the best C code I have ever seen
```

which is not desirable. Is there an elegant way of fixing/expressing the fact that I want to skip the loop entirely if there are no c files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`nullglob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-pathname-expansion) option. Then the expansion will be empty if there is no match.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.c; do …
```

Note that this is a bash-specific construct, it won't work under plain `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=`ls -1 *.c 2> /dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $n != 0 ]
then
    for f in *.c; do echo "That $f is the best C code I have ever seen"; done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, `shopt -s nullglob` will cause globs which do not match any files to return an empty expansion, rather than identity.

For POSIX, maybe something like

```
case *.c in '*.c' ) echo no match ;; esac
```

with the obvious pathological exception that you might separately need to check if there is a single matching file whose name is literally `*.c`.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
for f in `ls -1 *.c`; do
 echo That $f is the best C code I have ever seen
done
```

Comment: True, this works in the case where `*.c` matches nothing, but could fail to work as expected if there are matches of files with whitespace contained in the names.

Comment: Say you have one file, `foo bar.c`. The loop, after the command substitution, is equivalent to `for f in foo bar.c; do`: `f` is set to `foo`, then `bar.c`.